# What is- zsh: segmentation fault in c programming and how to solve this fault?

Tags: c, zsh, fault

I have got zsh: segmentation fault in this program and I don't know why. How run this program without this fault.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int old[9]={'3','5','7','8','8','6','2','3','5'};
    int new[3][3], r, c, n;

    for (r=0;r<3;r++){
        for (c=0;c<3;c++){
            new[r][c]=old[n];
            n++;
        }
    }

    printf("New array is:\n");
    for (r=0;r<3;r++){
        for (c=0;c<3;c++){
            printf("%d",new[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

> ┌──(imsourobh㉿kali)-[~/Documents/codes/c/cse]
> └─$ cd "/home/imsourobh/Documents/codes/c/cse/" && gcc >array.c -o array && "/home/imsourobh/Documents/codes/c/cse/"array
> zsh: segmentation fault  "/home/imsourobh/Documents/codes>c/cse/"array

Comment: You forgot to initialize n. So you are probably attempting to access the old array past its end (or before its beginning).

Comment: Please remove the zsh tag for clarity. If your C program does a SEGF, this is unrelated to what kind of parent process was running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `n` variable is uninitialized. This means it's value is undefined, and using it to index an array is undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means anything can happen. Your program *might* have worked exactly as you planned.

Or you might have gotten a segfault, which is what actually did happen.

To avoid this, `n` should have been initialized to `0`.

As a sidenote, since `n++` returns the value of `n`, *then* increments it, you could save yourself a line of code:

```
new[r][c] = old[n++];
```

Or you might avoid the need for `n` at all by using some math. Here I've defined constants for the dimensions of your two-dimensional array. I've also locally scoped `r` and `c` to their respective loops as they aren't needed outside of that scope. Lastly, I've used `size_t` rather than `int`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 3

int main(void) {
    int old[] = {'3', '5', '7', '8', '8', '6', '2', '3', '5'};
    int new[ROWS][COLS];

    for (size_t r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < COLS; c++) {
            new[r][c] = old[r * COLS + c];
        }
    }

    printf("New array is:\n");

    for (size_t r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < COLS; c++) {
            printf("%d ", new[r][c]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are several issues in the code.

First in `old[]` array. The datatype is `int` but the contents are characters. If you want to use the ASCII values then it is fine.

And another issue is using `new` as the name of the array. new is a c++ language [keyword](https://www.w3schools.in/cplusplus/keywords). Better to change the name.

And for the last, the variable `n` is not initialized. Probably the compiler can through garbage values to `n`. I modified the code and looks like working fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int old[9]={'3','5','7','8','8','6','2','3','5'}; // the ASCII values of charancters are assigned
    int new_num[3][3], r, c, n = 0 ; //changed the name of array and initialized n 

    for (r=0;r<3;r++){
        for (c=0;c<3;c++){
            new_num[r][c]=old[n];
            n++;
        }
    }

    printf("New array is:\n");
    for (r=0;r<3;r++){
        for (c=0;c<3;c++){
            printf("%d ",new_num[r][c]); //added a space in printf() for better visualization
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: No, `new` is not special in the C language.  It is a keyword in C++, but C is not C++.  That said, I recommend avoiding C++ keywords in C programs.  For consistency, I would have renamed the `old` array too.  The constants like `'3'` are 'integer character constants' — they are of type `int` in C (but of type `char` in C++, but C is not C++ nor vice versa.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, I believe AYK was saying that `char` would be a more appropriate type for the elements of the array, and there's a good chance that's true. The fact that `'3'` is an `int` is not relevant. We assign `int` values to `char` variables all the time. Anyway, AYK oddly made no correction for that "issue".

Comment: Yes, `new` is not a token for C.  My mistake. But for the old[] array, if the intention is to use the ASCII values of the chars then it is fine. But if it is required for output as numbers better to change the datatype or remove the '',